# No puedo sumar una columna de mi formulario

Tags: html

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]He aprendido harto en esta página y me han ayudado harto también y ahora tengo un problemita con la suma de una columna de una tabla que tengo en un formulario, quiero sumar los subtotales y me arroja siempre 0, espero puedan ayudarme a ver en qué me estoy equivocando, este es el código, tengo dos formularios,  uno me muestra un número de orden asociado a nombre correo etc... y tengo una búsqueda por el número de orden y en el segundo formulario me muestra el detalle, pero quiero mostrar la suma total de los subtotales y no me resulta, también les de dejo la imagen de como se ve en la web.

```html
<?php
$conexion=mysqli_connect ("xxx","xxxx","xxx.","xxxx");
$productos= "SELECT* from orden_de_compra";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lamg="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-widch, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
   <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">    
    </head>    
    <body>
<div class="container" >
    <table class="table table-bordered mt-2">
    <thead>
    <caption class="caption-top">Ordenes de Venta</caption>
    <tr>
    <th >N° de Orden</th>
    <th  >Nombre</th>
    <th  >Correo</th>
    <th  >Dirección</th>
    <th  >Teléfono</th>    
    </tr>
    </thead>      
    
    
    <?php
$resultado =mysqli_query($conexion, $productos);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
 ?>
        
<tbody>
    <th ><?php echo $row["ordendecompra"];?></th>    
    <th ><?php echo $row["nombre"];?></th>
    <th ><?php echo $row["correo"];?></th>    
    <th ><?php echo $row["direccion"];?></th>
    <th ><?php echo $row["telefono"];?></th>  
</tbody>
<?php }mysqli_free_result($resultado);?>
<br>
<br>
<br>
     </table>       
</div>       
        
        
        <?php
$conexion=mysqli_connect ("xxxx","xxxx","xxxx","xxxx");
$n_orden=$_POST["busquedaorden"];
$productos= "SELECT* from productos_vendidos WHERE n_orden ='$n_orden'";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lamg="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-widch, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
   <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    </head>
    
    <body>
<form method="post" action="buscarorden.php">
<div class="container" >
    <table class="table table-bordered mt-2">

        <thead>
            <caption class="caption-top">Detalle de orden de Venta</caption>
            <tr>
                
                
<p>

    Búsqueda de orden: <input type="search" name="busquedaorden" >

    <input type="submit" value="Buscar">

  </p>                
                
<th >Código</th>
<th  >descripción</th>
    <th  >Existencia</th>
    <th  >Precio de Venta</th>
    <th  >Cantidad</th>
    <th  >Subtotal</th>
    <th  >Numero de Orden</th>
     </tr>
    </thead>    
    
    <?php 

$resultado =mysqli_query($conexion, $productos);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
 ?>
<tbody>
    <th ><?php echo $row["codigo"];?></th>
    <th ><?php echo $row["descripcion"];?></th>
    <th ><?php echo $row["existencia"];?></th>
    <th ><?php echo $row["precioventa"];?></th>
    <th ><?php echo $row["cantidad"]; ?></th>       
    <th><input name="subtotal[]" id= "subtotal "class = "subtotal" value="<?php echo $row["subtotal"];?>" readonly="readonly"></th>
    <th ><?php echo $row["n_orden"];?></th>
</tbody>
<?php }mysqli_free_result($resultado);?>
<br>
<br>
<br>   
     <tfoot>
            <td colspan="4"></td>
            <td>Total </td>
            <td>
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <span class="input-group-text border-0 bg-white">$</span>
            <input type="text" class="claseTotal border-0 form-control bg-white" disabled value="0">
      </div>
      </td>
      </tfoot>
      </table>   

</div>  
        &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
        &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
        &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
        &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
        &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
        &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
        <input onclick="location.href='https://jostore.cl/administrador.html' " value="Volver" type="button"><br>        
        
    </form>           
       <script>
           $(document).ready(function() {         
          var subtotal = 0;
          $('#subtotal tbody').find('th').each(function(i,el) {
            subtotal += parseFloat($(this).find('th').eq(0).text());
          });
          $('#claseTotal tfoot td').eq(0).Text("total"+subtotal);         
        });        
        </script>        
        </body>    
   </html>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Claudia, si te ayudó la respuesta, considera marcarla como aceptada en el checklist que aparece a la izquierda de la respuesta. Quien te ayudó puso todo su tiempo y esfuerzo en la respuesta de manera gratuita, y lo único que espera a cambio es que la aceptes. Sé agradecida y márcala como correcta. ¡Muy buena suerte con tu problema!

Comment: Está demás su comentario estimado, obviamente que siempre estoy agradecida de quién me ayuda, es algo agresiva su opinión.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interpretas mál el uso del [selector de jquery](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/). El selector de jquery es lo que va entre paŕéntesis precedido por el signo **$**. Cuando quieres señalar a un **id=** debes precederlo con el signo de la almohadilla (**#**), pero si quieres señalar a una clase (**class=**) entonces debes usar un punto (**.**), y encerrarlos a su vez entre comillas (dobles o simples, como prefieras).

En tu caso, estás haciendo esto:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {         
          var subtotal = 0;
          $('#subtotal tbody').find('th').each(function(i,el) {
            subtotal += parseFloat($(this).find('th').eq(0).text());
          });
          $('#claseTotal tfoot td').eq(0).Text("total"+subtotal);         
        });
```

cuando debería ser esto, tal como tienes diseñado tu HTML:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {         
          var subtotal = 0;
          $('.subtotal').each(function(i,el) {
            subtotal += parseFloat($(this).val());
          });
          $('.claseTotal').val(subtotal);
        });
```

**Otros problemas:**

1. No uses el mismo id en un bucle, tal como haces aquí:

```
id= "subtotal "
```

pues no sirve de nada y si intentas señalarlos a todos es probable que solo encuentre el primero.

2. No pegues los atributos ni dejes espacio en un **id=**, tal como haces aquí:

```
id= "subtotal "class = "subtotal"
```

en todo caso deberia ser así:

```
id= "subtotal" class = "subtotal"
```

pero remitiéndome al punto 1, quíta ese **id** directamente y deja la clase para que el javascript modificado de esta respuesta funcione bien.

3. No uses **`<th>`** dentro de un **tbody** para conseguir negritas, rompes con la estructura básica de una tabla en HTML. Dentro de un **tbody** las columnas usan el elemento **`<td>`**. Si quieres que todas sean negritas prueba con:

```
<tbody class="fw-bold">
```

tal como dice la [documentación de bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/text/#font-weight-and-italics) respecto al texto.

4. Inicias el documento dos veces, con dos etiquetas `<html>, <head> y <body>`.  debes eliminar la segunda, tan solo deben aparecer una vez.
5. No estás llamando al script de jquery en el `<head>` y por eso no se te ejecuta ningún elemento que usa su sintaxis.
6. No cierras el `<form>` que intentas usar para el botón Buscar, sino que lo dejas abierto hasta el final de documento y eso puede provocar comportamientos impredecibles al pulsar botones (si los hay).

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por tus observaciones, las hice, pero igual no me suma

Comment: Revisa de nuevo mi respuesta, he agregado más cosas que no habia visto antes.

Comment: hice los cambios pero igual no me suma

Comment: Listo, ya lo solucioné y tenías razón sobre el script no lo estaba llamando desde el head, ahora si me funcionó, lo otro que no me resulta es que se vea bien el tamaño de la página, solo en chrome se ve bien, pero en los otros navegadores no lo muestra completo

Comment: ¿que es lo que no se muestra completo?  ¿que falta en los otros navegadores?

Comment: mira este pastebin  https://pastebin.com/9kzaMP0v  me muestra la pagina cortada al lado derecho de la pantalla  puse la imagen arriba de como se ve

Comment: es solo esa pagina que se muestra la columna incompleta en el navegador, funciona perfecto pero se ve incompleto, el Bootstrap que debo arreglar verdad?

Comment: Utiliza la clase `form-control` en todos los input que puedas, y verás que se redimensionan para que todo quepa en la página. Mira [aquí](https://jsfiddle.net/ts0kw45a/)

Comment: Lo voy a cambiar enseguida y comentaré que sucede, estimado masterguru un abrazo

Comment: Hice dos pruebas, en la primera no me resultó porque había cambiado la clase de la columna total por la que me recomendaste y dejó de sumar los subtotales y en la segundo cambié solo los input que se obtienen de la base de datos y ahí si se ajustaron y logré visualizar la pagina completa en todos los navegadores, muchísimas gracias masterguru, estaba en clases por eso es que no respondí antes.